# prevent p span element from moving around while page loading

Tags: html, css, morris.js

I have a morris graph in angular application which shows data on page load. I tried to have name 'Population' on y-axis using html, css like this:

[image]

But when the page is initially loading, this span 'Population' is moving upwards into other div which is above this and when the graph is loaded, it is coming into it's position.

css:

```
#Graph{
      margin-left: 4%;
      height:100%;
    }
     #Graph p {
      position:relative;
      float:left;
      width:50%;
      border-radius:5px;
      -moz-border-radius:5px;
      vertical-align: center;
      margin-left: -3%;
    }
     #Graph p span {
      font-size: 15px;
      color: '#606060';
      width:100%; /* same as height of .rotateObj */
      -webkit-transform-origin:84px 70px;
      display:inline-block;
      -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
      text-align:center;
    }
```

html:

```
 <div class="card-body" id="Graph">
        <div id ="graphElement"></div>
        <p><span>Population</span></p>
```

I want the 'Population' to be in this graph div until the graph loads and should not move upwards into other div. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Of course the whole thing moves up, if the graph element is not there yet to span up the container element to begin with … Either give it a fixed height (if possible), or, if you want to keep it responsive and at least know the aspect ratio of the graph, use the padding-bottom hack.

Comment: so you are saying to use padding-bottom on the span?

Comment: No, not at all. https://www.google.com/search?q=padding-bottom%20hack

Comment: I didn't quite understand. can you give me an example

Comment: Can I not use position absolute, relative?

Comment: The first result, http://andyshora.com/css-image-container-padding-hack.html, has a pretty decent explanation of how the technique works, and examples as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172987/discussion-between-yer-and-cbroe).

Comment: Actually that works. Thank you @CBroe